# Is "Disk failure is imminent" causing the errors I am experiencing?

Tags: hard-disk, libraries

I am getting SMART Status 184 end to end error, and "Disk failure is imminent", suggesting I need to get a new hard drive, and I will do.

But now I am also getting error messages such as when running vim:

```
vim: error while loading shared libraries: libgnomeui-2.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

or apt-get update:

```
apt-get: error while loading shared libraries: /usr/lib/libapt-pkg.so.4.11: invalid ELF header
```

Just wondering if the imminent disk failure is causing these problems?

System is Ubuntu 10.10 dual boot xp 64bit

Comment: Disk failures sometimes cause data corruption, but more often they result in unreadable data. Do a memory test; that can trigger data corruption that goes undetected for a while.

Comment: SMART is usually incorrect by omission: i.e. failing to warn you when a disk is about to die. When SMART warns you like this, feel lucky, and assume failure is indeed imminent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disk failure can cause all sorts of problems, as files, binaries, libraries etc may become corrupted so the safest assumption is **yes**.

So ensure you have all data backed up, and get a new disk now.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely: libraries fail to load or get corrupted because of disk failures.